# VK Api получить ID пользователя в Iframe через ОФФ приложение

Tags: javascript, php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет,у меня есть IFrame приложение,в ПК версии получаю ID так:

```
$userinfo = json_decode($_REQUEST['api_result']); 
$vk_api = $userinfo->response[0]->id;
setcookie('profile_viewer_uid', $vk_api, time()+86400*365, '/');
```

В принципе работает,не всегда правда с первого раза,но выводит.

Как получить ID юзера в Direct Games?
Mobile SDK вроде подключил.

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
VK.init(function() {
    console.log('yes')
}, function() {
    console.log('fail')
}, '5.84');
</script>
```

Вот как выглядит сейчас,поле ID пустое.На ПК версии пишет ID пользователя. [image: ja]